# Using String in Switch Statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to create a switch statement based upon a two character string. However, this doesn't seem to work and always evaluates to the default. So, could someone please show me the correct way to do it?

Here is my (presumably incorrect) code:

```
string GetPieceCode(GameObject piece)
{
    string pieceCode = "";
    Debug.Log(piece.gameObject);
    pieceCode = piece.ToString().Remove(2,2);
    Debug.Log(pieceCode);
    return pieceCode;
}    

Debug.Log(pieceType);
switch (pieceType)
{
    case "BP":
        Debug.Log("Black Pawn Selected");
        break;
    case "WP":
        Debug.Log("White Pawn Selected");
        break;
    case "WB":
        print("White Bishop Selected");
        break;
    case "BB":
        print("Black Bishop Selected");
        break;
    case "WK":
        print("White Knight Selected");
        break;
    case "BK":
        print("Black Knight Selected");
        break;
    case "WR":
        print("White Roook Selected");
        break;
    case "BR":
        print("Black Rook Selected");
        break;
    case "WKing":
        print("White King Selected");
        break;
    case "WQueen":
        print("White Queen Selected");
        break;
    case "BKing":
        print("Black King Selected");
        break;
    case "BQueen":
        print("Black Queen Selected");
        break;
    default;
        debug.log("Error");
        break;
}
```

The initial `Debug.Log(pieceType)` prints out a 2 character string code which shows that it matches the case values. So I don't see what is going wrong.

Also, `print()` and `Debug.Log()` are identical in this context.

Comment: Are you sure that it's printing an _identical_ two character code?  Any whitespace after it etc perhaps?

Comment: What is the exact value of `pieceType` at runtime?  `switch` statements can use strings without any problem.

Comment: What typ,e of variable is pieceType?  Maybe you need pieceType.ToString()

Comment: `switch` is case-sensitive - is the two-character code uppercase?

Comment: What if you try something simple like `Debug.Log(pieceType == "BP")` or `Debug.Log(pieceType.Equals("BP"))`? Does that evaluate to true? If not, then the characters in the string aren't quite what they appear. Maybe there's a carriage return on the end, or a space, or they're some random other language character that just so happens to look like BP

Comment: pieceType is a string, and the outputs are exactly `BP` or `WP` etc

Comment: thanks @sab669, that's evaluating to false... but I have absolutely no idea why! Will add more information to initial question.

Comment: Also, it's just `default:` and not `case default:`. I don't think that's what's causing this, but it certainly isn't helping!

Comment: @JamesHughes: Don't just look at the rendered printable string.  There could be any number of non-printable characters there.  When you debug, convert the `pieceType` string into a character array and see what's in that array.  Clearly there's something different from the expected values.

Comment: You need to modify your sample code to include the assignment of `pieceType` that **reproduces** your issue. I think in doing that you will solve your own issue.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help... I've worked it out by doing what @David said, I'll save it as an answer.

Comment: `piece.ToString().Remove(2,2);` looks incredibly suspicious to me. Also `(B|W)(King|Queen)` will never be hit in this example.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, yeah that was the issue in the end and yeah, that just twigged, I'll have to work something else out for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within the face that I assumed the `GameObject piece` would return only the 3 character name assigned to it within Unity. Thus, I assumed that to get the first 2 for the code I would only have to remove the first digit.

However, all of my debugging attempts were compromised by the fact that I thought (incorrectly) that `BP(UnityEngine.GameObject)` as an output was merely `BP` as a string with some added debug information.

The correct method of generating the piece code is:

```
string GetPieceCode(GameObject piece)
    {
        string pieceCode = "";
        Debug.Log(piece.gameObject);
        pieceCode = piece.ToString().Substring(0,2);
        Debug.Log(pieceCode);
        return pieceCode;
    }
```

Thanks for everyone's help.

Edit: Although not part of the original problem, I changed the codes for Kings and Queens to `B|Wk` and `B|Wq` respectively, making use of the case sensitivity.

Comment: How do you know if it's a King or Queen if you're using `Substring(0,2)`?

Comment: @sab669 thanks for the help, learning a new engine and a new language at the same time is driving me up the wall.